# como pasar parámetros por PreparedStatement ah una consulta ha postgres?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, prepared-statements

Hola tengo el siguiente código

```
try {
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_facultades.FACULTAD where idFacultad = ? ";
 PreparedStatement statement = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
     statement.setInt(1,1);

     ResultSet resultado = statement.executeQuery();

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

me da error..

ejecuto la query en mi postgrest y me devuelve error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he notado que si se puede ejecutar si es que pongo de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo modificar mi String sql para que pueda funcionar correctamente.

Muchas Gracias. !!!!

**añado**

estructura de la tabla..  (creada desde el pgAdmin 4)

```
CREATE TABLE bd_facultades.facultad
(
    "nomFacultad" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    idfacultad integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT facultad_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idfacultad)
)
```

Comment: Cuál es el error que tienes al ejecutar el programa Java?

Comment: En Postgresql los nombres de tablas y de columna son por defecto *case sensitive*, o sea, que si en el `CREATE TABLE` la tabla ha sido declarada con el nombre `facultad` y la columna ha sido declarada con el nombre `idfacutad` (todo en minúscula) tienes que ponerlo del mismo modo en tu consulta. Simplemente prueba a escribir la consulta así: **`"SELECT * FROM bd_facultades.facultad where idfacultad = ?"`**  debería funcionar. Evita también los espacios sobrantes en las variables de cadena, más aún tratándose de una consulta preparada.

Comment: en realidad no es así..  en postgres cuando creo un campo como text por ejemplo campo1 ...   lo crea correcto . pero lo crea como  "campo1"  (con los simbolos) .  si creo otro campo .. ejemplo campo2 ..  como integer.. en este no le pone los "" ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues... Exactamente como te dice la salida del pgAdmin: no existe la columna `idfacultad`. Estás intentando obtener algo que no existe.

Ahora bien, ¿por qué sí funciona cuando escribes `"idFacultad"`? Esto te puede ayudar: [Sintaxis de Identificadores en PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html). Está en inglés, obviamente, al ser la documentación oficial.

Traducido al español, el nombre de la columna `idFacultad`, está definido exactamente así, con la F mayúsculas, por lo que si intentas buscar algo en una columna/campo que se llame `idfacultdad` va a dar error, esa columna no existe.

Cuando creas una tabla y los identificadores de las columnas/campos están entrecomillados, estás diciendo crea esta tabla con los campos tal cual están escritos, y para PostgreSQL, y otras bases de datos, si no estoy equivocado, los campos entrecomillados son case-sensitive.

`idfacultad` es distinto de `"idFacultad"` y distinto de `"IDfacultad"` y distinto de `"IDFACULTAD"`...

Y por ende, este error no tiene nada que ver con que la consulta o el query sea preparada o una consulta normal. Para muchos ¿expertos?, el crear tablas con campos entrecomillados es toda una ignominia, un sacrilegio, tú decides, lo importante es que seas congruente: o todos los campos de todas las tablas van entrecomillados o ningún campo va entrecomillado, pero no mezcles, mezclar es malo, je je.

Se me olvidaba, intenta ejecutar el query de la siguiente manera:

```
"SELECT * FROM bd_facultades.facultad where \"idFacultad\" = ?"
```

en tu código Java.

Gracias E. Betanzos por tu corrección :-)

Y bueno, cuando quieras hacer referencia a una columna, tabla, esquema... que se hallan definido así: `"Mitabla"` `"miCampoIncreíble"` vas a tener que escribirlo así, tal cual, con entrecomillado doble:

```
select * from "Mitabla";

select * from "Mitabla" where "miCampoIncreíble" = 'valor';
```

Y, dependiendo del lenguaje de programación de tu sistema/aplicación, escribes la consulta sql con los escapes de caracteres necesarios.

Comment: El código que propones no funciona en java ya que las comillas simples indican un literal de `char`. Por este motivo vas a tener un error de compilación. Lo que se debe hacer es escapar las doble comillas dentro del `String`. Algo como esto: "SELECT * FROM ... \"idFacultad\" = ? ". El resto perfecto.

Comment: Oh ok, gracias por tu comentario. En realidad no programo en java, hace décadas realicé un programa cuando cursaba mi carrera universitaria, así que olvidé mucho de java. Editaré la respuesta, agradecido una vez más.

Comment: Eso suele ocurrir cuando se programa con varios lenguajes xD!

Comment: agregue la estructura de la tabla .. esta ha sido creada desde el pgAdmin y como ven . cuando es text.   crea el nombre con ""  ("nomFacultad") y cuando es integer  no pone los ""   (idfacultad),   por este mismo motivo me aparecía el error, esto es correcto ?  osea todos los campos que sean text .. siempre tendrán que llevar los "" en java?

Comment: Mi recomendación: crea objetos (tablas, campos, esquemas, bases de datos...) desde la query tool de pgAdmin o desde el editor de código sql. Si no estás familiarizado con el lenguaje sql y utilizas siempre la interfaz gráfica del pgAdmin para crear objetos, entonces siempre verifica la pestaña sql, casi todas las ventanas de creación de objetos en pgAdmin tienen una pestaña llamada SQL que te previsualiza cómo y/o cuál va a ser el query que se va a ejecutar.

Comment: pgAdmin está diseñado para crear objetos, tal cual los escriba el usuario, por lo tanto, si escribes idFacultad para crear un campo del tipo que sea (text, char, integer, character varying, inet...) pgAdmin añadirá comillas dobles. Ya que la sintaxis por defecto de PostgreSQL es en minúsculas, al intentar crear algo que no sea todo en minúsculas pgAdmin le colocará las comillas dobles.

Comment: Muchas gracias.   en ese caso realizare los create table desde una query, y así me evito que lo cree de ese modo.. muchas gracias. daré como resulta la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Debes hacer referencia a la tabla indicando del campo que deseas

```
try {
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_facultades.FACULTAD where facultad.idFacultad = ? ";
 PreparedStatement statement = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
     statement.setInt(1,1);

     ResultSet resultado = statement.executeQuery();

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

de hecho el mismo "hint", sugiere este cambio:

> Probablente quiera hacer referencia a la columna "facultad.idFacultad"

Comment: hice el cambio en su momento y me siguió marcando el error.

Comment: Que mensaje se muestra cuando realizaste el cambio?

Comment: añadí .. la estructura de la tabla que cree, el problema es como esta creando el nombre de los campos..  cuando es text  .. le pone los "" y cuando es integer no les pone.. y esto afecta al momento de realizar las consultas.   esto siempre sera así ? o que debo de hacer para que los nombres los cree normal.. sin ""